# MySQL - Recurring Event with random time

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an event that is recurring with a random time between 1 and 45 minutes. This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE EVENT `user_creator` ON SCHEDULE EVERY (1 + RAND( ) *45) MINUTE
DO
    INSERT INTO userTable (firstName, lastName) VALUES ('John', 'Smith')
```

It executes just fine, however, it doesn't randomize the time once its been executed. In other words, it stays to be the random number that was assigned when it first was executed.

Comment: MySQL scheduler will evaluate expression at creation time and will use that as interval.

Comment: event_scheduler execute tasks every interval just like a timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to store the altering in a completion block, so, I simply just added into the action.

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT `user_creator` ON SCHEDULE EVERY (1 + RAND( ) *45) MINUTE

DO

    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO userTable (firstName,lastName) VALUES ('John','Smith');

    ALTER EVENT `user_creator` ON SCHEDULE EVERY (1 + RAND( ) *45) MINUTE;

END |


delimiter ;
```